# ListView of Linearlayouts

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have an app where I have some linear layouts--(first_linear,second_linear,third_linear,fourth_linear). In each linear layout there are different items--

(i) an edittext and an image button
(ii)a textView and a spinner
(iii)two textViews
(iv) two textViews

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTaskName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/entName"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"

            />

        <ImageButton

            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:id="@+id/micro_phone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/first_linear"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/typeEntry"
            android:text="Type"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnTaskType"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/third_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/second_linear"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/DateEntry"
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttvDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:onClick="edittxtDate"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fourth_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/third_linear"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/TimeEntry"
            android:text="Time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtvTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:onClick="edittxtTime"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

But now I want to keep those linear layouts in a listView. How can I do that?
Should I use baseAdapter or arrayAdapter?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you post an image of what you expect to develop?

Comment: No need to put them in a listview. That'd be more work for nothing because you have 3 different items out of 4. If you really want to go that way then look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: You don't need to use a listview. use a scrollview instead to wrap them around the whole views. I'd suggest using a single `<RelativeLayout>` and design the whole. Using too many linear layout is just bad coding. Also point to note <ScrollView> can have only one direct child.

Comment: It you want to generate list then use `ListView` else `ScrollView` will do your work

Comment: Should i use an int array containing ids or a linearlayout array?

Comment: -Create one adapter item layout and put all the components into linear layout in that xml.

-after that according to your requirement set visibility of the xml file components.

-and last step inflate this xml file into adapter and set this adapter to listview or recycleview.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to just have the long list of controls scroll then use a scrollview.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ... All your linear layouts here
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But here i cannot have each element seperated. This will not look good.